# How to use Jenkins Amazon EC2 Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**Goal:**
I would like to use [Amazon Ec2 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) to add dynamic slaves to Jenkins based on the load.

**Architecture:**
Jenkins Master + 4 slaves + dynamic slaves (based on the requirement)
1st job runs on dynamic slave (no concurrent jobs) - label1 (ami-12345)
2nd job runs concurrently on dynamic slaves - label2 (ami-23314)

These two has different AMI and different labels.

**PROBLEM:**
first job is able to spin up the instance and executes the job everything looks good. If I run the 2nd job Jenkins able to spin up the instance, However if jobs are queued up it's not adding new slaves.Even though I added the instance to 4 for that AMI.

Jenkins v1.656
Amazon EC2 plugin v1.31

Answer (score 1):

I tried to minimize the number of executors on master and try to run the job, But no luck. Changed EC2 instance size to little bit low and increased number of executors(in order increase more load the slave). Job waited for couple of minutes(~5 minutes) and started another slave.

Solution:
Your cluster should be overloaded for more than couple of minutes to add a new dynamic slave.